# Multiple parallel sessions as a single user

Tags: kubuntu, session, sddm

On my graphical desktop ubuntu computer, I can start multiple parallel sessions with the same user. Is this a bug? If it's a feature, what is the purpose behind it?

To do this, I click on "New Session" under the "Leave" menu. That brings up a menu where I can choose between several sessions to switch to, or click a button labelled "New Session". Clicking "New Session" brings up the following menu:
[image]

There's another button here called "New Session", and if I click it, it comes up with another menu:
[image]
where I can select my user from the list and enter my password to log in. I can then do the whole thing again to start a third session (and fourth...). To get back my original session, I logged out and was then able to log into the "parent" session.

The first time this happened was an accident, as I didn't realise I still had a session running. It led to interesting issues such as firefox and libreoffice failing to start, as they were locked to the other session.

P.S. This is all directly at the computer itself, no remote desktops or ssh.

Comment: related: [what are parallel sessions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950535/what-are-parallel-sessions?noredirect=1&lq=1)… oh, that's where you came from :)

Comment: What flavour of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: Kubuntu 16.04, but I have gnome installed too.

Comment: If you open a terminal window and type "who" you will be surprised with how many sessions you opened!

Comment: Once you have two different desktop environments installed, things can get complicated. You say you have "gnome installed too". If you do plan to file a bug, please do so from a pure DE. I have a clean Kubuntu 16.04 with the kubuntu-backports ppa installed and don't see a "leave" option.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose behind it is perhaps "just because". If that feature irritates you, you should be able to switch it off by removing the sessions menu in the display manager (LightDM, SDDM) login configuration, if possible.

Comment: Since this is Kubuntu, it's more likely to be SDDM.

Comment: @muru I couldn't see anything about this in the SDDM settings under System Settings. Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Comment: Now that I know what's happening, it probably won't irritate me. It definitely did irritate me when I logged into what I thought was a fresh session, and was told that an instance of firefox was already running. If there isn't a purpose behind the feature, and there is potential for issues like mine, doesn't that imply that something in the design or the implementation is not quite right?

Comment: It may have some purpose for some users. Said that, this kind of gallopping featuritis/bells & whistles is what made me turning my back to KDE after having used it a long time before version 4...